# Header to describe available `content-type` responses?

Tags: http, http-headers

It's a little cumbersome to scrape through the HTTP RFC for this particular question, so I'm hoping someone can help me short-circuit an answer:

Does the HTTP spec contain functionality for a server to declare that a particular URL exposes multiple content type options, and what those options might be? In short, an OPTIONS call has the `allow: PUT, POST, GET` etc. header but is there something similar for `returnable-media-types: application/json, text/csv` etc.?